# Content assist suggestions not showing directly

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I am using Eclipse Neon. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, Eclipse shows a popup on the bottom right of Eclipse screen which includes a text `Content Assist Ctrl+Space`. When I click this dialog, then Eclipse shows suggestions:

[image]

How can I see suggestions directly after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>?

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_ filter for `ctrl+space`: are there more commands than _Content Assist_ bound to this shortcut? By the way, Eclipse Neon is pretty old. Please upgrade.

Comment: thanks for your help. İt is solved with your way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that **no other command** than *Content Assist* is **bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>**:

In ***Window > Preferences: General > Keys* filter for `ctrl+space`** and bind other command to other keys.